# Parser and Lexer Files Not Auto Generated by Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, antlr, antlr3, antlrv3ide

I'm using the antlr-3.4-complete-no-antlrv2.jar version of ANTLR on Eclipse Indigo.

I have installed the ANTLR IDE plugin along with ZEST and GEF.  When I generate a combined grammar file and add a header, lexer header and a rule, Eclipse doesn't generate the Parser and Lexer files.

If I use antlr-3.2.jar it does. I can generate the Lexer and Parser files (using antlr-3.4.*) outside of Eclipse using ***java -classpath antlr-3.4-complete-no-antlrv2.jar org.antlr.Tool Sample.g***.

Is there any way to turn this on in Eclipse for version 3.4 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See this thread on SourceForge

http://sourceforge.net/projects/antlrv3ide/forums/forum/768683/topic/4689005

You can't use the no antlrv2 version.

That may or may not fix the problem, I have everything set up correctly but as others have found and reported on SourceForge it simply won't output any Java.

Comment: The main part in that link to focus on is "To enable ANTLR support for the project, in the Package Explorer window (left pane) right-click the project just created and select Configure, Convert to ANTLR project.". That fixed it for me.